# Getting name of containing Folder

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script that I want to copy in many directories

Inside this script, How can I initialize the variable

```
PARENT_FOLDER
```

in a way to store in it the name (and not the absolute path) of the folder containing this script?

Note that this script may be run from any folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "name (and not the path) of the folder" mean precisely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

Comment: Sorry i was not precise. by path I meant absolute path, and by name I mean't just the name. Your answer is exactly what I need (+1 and accepted) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. You re right. Seems google failed this time , or maybe me :)

Comment: However it s not really a duplicate and there is still the need of
    PARENT_FOLDER=${PARENT_FOLDER##*/}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under most circumstances, the following gets the absolute path to the directory that the script is in:

```
PARENT_FOLDER=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
```

(OSX and BSD might lack the `-f` option without which the path may still contain symbolic links.)

If you just want the name of the final directory in the path, just add one step:

```
PARENT_FOLDER=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
PARENT_FOLDER=${PARENT_FOLDER##*/}
```

On systems lacking `readlink -f` but for which bash is available:

```
PARENT_FOLDER="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
PARENT_FOLDER=${PARENT_FOLDER##*/}
```

And if lacking both `readlink -f` and bash:

```
PARENT_FOLDER="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
PARENT_FOLDER=${PARENT_FOLDER##*/}
```

Comment: Yes. It creates a problem on mac osx with the option -f so better use the solution mentioned by  @Adrian Frühwirth

Comment: @IssamT. OSX is often a little different.  I updated my answer also.

Comment: I think this now that this is a full answer to pretty much anyone. Nice job :)

Answer (score 2):

To get parent folder of Current Directory you can use following command

```
PARENT_FOLDER=$(pwd | awk -F"/" 'OFS="/"{$NF=""}1')
```

**To Update**

> also below command can work
>
> from man page of command dirname
> ***Print NAME with its trailing /component removed; if NAME contains no /’s, output ‘.’ (meaning the current directory).***

PARENT_FOLDER=$(dirname "$PWD")
or

```
PARENT_FOLDER=$(dirname "$0")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PARENT_FOLDER=$(pwd | awk -F / '{if ($NF!="") print $NF; else print "/"}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that worked for me on both mac and linux is

```
PARENT_FOLDER="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
PARENT_FOLDER=${PARENT_FOLDER##*/}
```

It is a combination of the answer given in this link:

[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

And the answer given by @John1024